# Git flow - create feature branch off another feature branch

Tags: git, git-flow

I having been using `git flow` for a while now. I am curious to learn about a specific use case.

For one of my projects I have a ticket for a new website feature. This ticket depends on many sub-tasks. I would like to create a feature branch for the main ticket, and then for each sub-task create a feature branch off of the parent feature branch.

Let's assume I have a ticket PROJ-500 and I create a feature branch for it

```
git flow feature start PROJ-500
```

Then I want to integrate tickets `PROJ-501` through `PROJ-515` into `PROJ-500` before integrating the whole thing into `develop`. Is there a way for me to do something like

```
git flow feature start PROJ-511 -b PROJ-500
```

Then over time these sub-tasks get completed and when their feature is finished, the branch is merged into `PROJ-500`.

```
git flow feature finish PROJ-511
```

The above command would merge `PROJ-511` into `PROJ-500`

And once all sub-tasks are completed then `PROJ-500` will be finished and merged into `develop`.

This way the new website feature is integrate into develop as a single unit rather than piecemeal.

Comment: Does this not do it? `git flow feature start PROJ-511 PROJ-500`? The link you posted in the comment to DerekS' answer suggests that it should.

Answer (score 131, accepted):

You can create a sub-feature branch via

```
git flow feature start PROJ-511 feature/PROJ-500
```

But you cannot use the GitFlow tool to merge the branch back into the main feature branch because if you do

```
git flow feature finish PROJ-511
```

the feature will be merged into `develop`. Ergo **sub-features are not supported**, you need to do it manually.

**Alternatives:** The requirement is not new, though. There is an [open issue](https://github.com/nvie/gitflow/issues/208) as well as a [fork project](https://github.com/petervanderdoes/gitflow) claiming to support finishing features into branches other than `develop`. I also found a [pull request](https://github.com/nvie/gitflow/pull/278) with an implementation of that feature. You might want to try that modification and see if you are happy with it.

---

**Update 2019-12-13:** As user *Matěj Kříž* just mentioned in his comment, user *Tony Chemit* has written an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29353800/1082681) a few months after mine, pointing to [gitflow-avh](https://github.com/petervanderdoes/gitflow-avh#creating-featurereleasehotfixsupport-branches) as an alternative to the original gitflow product. It supports sub-features out of the box with the syntax shown above. Some years have passed by and nowadays the AVH edition is part of the normal installation of Git for Windows, I just verified this on my local box and tested the sub-feature option. I.e. for Windows users it just works right after Git installation.

Comment: @pymarco: Thanks for accepting the answer. I am curious though: Have you tried any of the alternatives? If so, which one and what was the outcome? Does it work as expected? Maybe other readers can learn something from your experience. :-)

Comment: Sorry, but I have not had time to return to this. I will try at some point.

Comment: Why the downvote? Downvotes are meant to be used for badly written, sloppy answers showing no sign of research effort or knowledge. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: If you use **gitflow-avh** version look lower at https://stackoverflow.com/a/29353800/472611 @tony-chemit answer

Answer (score 38):

As I understood, gitflow is quite abandoned.

**gitflow-avh** replaces it and offers this feature (see 
https://github.com/petervanderdoes/gitflow#creating-featurereleasehotfixsupport-branches).

I just try it and it works well to me.

```
git flow feature start PROJ-511 feature/PROJ-500
git flow feature finish PROJ-511
```

*PROJ-511* was merged into *feature/PROJ-500*.

Answer (score 16):

As already mentioned, we can start a new feature using any base branch with

```
git flow feature start PROJ-511 feature/PROJ-500
```

And to finish the sub feature we can temporarly change git flow configuration to use our feature branch instead of `develop`:

```
git flow config set develop feature/PROJ-500 && git flow feature finish PROJ-511
```

This way, git flow runs all commands and sanity checks. Finally, To restore config, we can run

```
git flow config set develop develop
```

Answer (score 8):

Update (November 5, 2020): As noted in the newer answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29353800/1855126), this is possible with gitflow-avh which has replaced the original git flow.

===================

Original Answer:

I don't think there is a method for this in git flow, but it is fairly simple with just git.

```
git checkout PROJ-500
git checkout -b PROJ-511
...do your PROJ-511 work...
git checkout PROJ-500
git merge PROJ-511
git branch -d PROJ-511
```

Comment: Thanks Derek for responding. Yes, I could follow that workflow. But git flow encapsulates a number of commands and sanity checks that I prefer to utilize for sub-feature development. For example here is a link to git-flow-feature - https://github.com/nvie/gitflow/blob/develop/git-flow-feature

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can make it from a base feature or even a branch as you like

```
git flow feature start new-feature-name original-feature-or-base-branch
```