# How can I create a new branch on develop?

Tags: git, git-flow

I use git flow and there are two branches called **develop** and **master** How can I create a new branch on **develop**?
Things I do:

```
git checkout develop
git flow feature start brokerage-branch
```

But this branch is created on the **master**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Git flow - create feature branch off another feature branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22948747/git-flow-create-feature-branch-off-another-feature-branch)

Answer (score 3):

The base branch for features (normally develop in Git Flow) can be configured and is likely set to *master* in your case. You can change it back to `develop` like this:

```
git config --local gitflow.branch.develop develop
```

When you start a new feature with `git flow feature start xyz`, it does not matter on what branch you currently are. The new feature branch is created from the configured branch.

Answer (score 2):

A example demonstrating a Feature Branch Flow is as follows.

```
git checkout master
git checkout -b develop
git checkout -b feature_branch
```

and in your case, it should checkout `develop` branch first and then try creating new feature

```
git flow init  # initialize gitflow
git branch  # check git branch here
git flow feature start feature_branch  # create feature branch
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on this link
http://danielkummer.github.io/git-flow-cheatsheet/

`feature start` should be created from `develop` branch